# Remove Version from Review in Google Play Console

Tags: google-play-console

I found some bugs in my code and need to submit a new version.

How do I remove or cancel the old version that is in review in Google Play Console?

I am hoping to not waste Google's time to review something that is already outdated.

Answer (score 13):

[Screenshot of the Issue]

[image]

I got the same issue you got when uploading two releases at the same time which both of them were in review mode, the simple answer is **"You don't have to worry, the latest version uploaded will get published on Google Play"**

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not believe this true. I had one track for production in review and wanted to have a newer version override it, and they were both listed as 'In review'. Unfortunately, the older version was reviewed first, released, and then the second one afterwards.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot remove versions of your app that you have published on the Google Play console. You can only halt releases for ones that have only been partially rolled out.

Instead, just submit the new version on the track and it will override the version that is in review. As it has a higher version code so it will replace the old version after it has been reviewed and users will download the new version.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true. I added a second version on the production track and now there are two of them in review.

Comment: Yes, but that new version you added will be the active one after review as it will replace the old version  because it has a has a higher version code.

Comment: I see your point, but it doesn’t really solve the original problem “ I am hoping to not waste Google's time to review something that is already outdated.”. Cheers

Comment: hopefully, a new submission will trigger them to stop reviewing the old track?

Comment: Moved ready to publish app from Alpha to Production track will again go into in review. So if i published the Alpha version and then move into production will not go in review further anymore, and that will be available in couple of hours.

Comment: This is not correct. They will review the builds in ordered received and newer ones to do not override the older ones.

Answer (score 0):

Just turn on managed publishing and wait until the newer one got reviewed. Then you can publish the newer one only.