# Is it okay to have two versions in revision on the developer console?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I uploaded accidentally one version that had crashes so I tried to eliminate it, but I saw that if I upload a newer version, the last one is the one that is published: [from other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65311285/20018861)
The problem is that I have seen one awnser in that post that has afraid me: "I see your point, but it doesn’t really solve the original problem “ I am hoping to not waste Google's time to review something that is already outdated.”. Cheers "

The awnser is correct, if I sumbit two versions of the same app at the same time, one version will be being reviewed for not being published later. It would waste Google's time then. Could that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

It will not be a problem. You can upload 100 versions of your app to the Play Store. Only the latest one you submit will be reviewed and published. Don't worry too much about "wasting Google's time," these reviewers are literally paid to review apps.